# Add voting buttons to the tag synonym overview page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, tag-synonyms

If you look at the [tag synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) and want to vote for a tag synonym (or just see its current vote count), you have to click through to the tags page and then to the info tab.

It would be much more convenient if the voting buttons were right there on the overview page, so that proposed synonyms can be voted on in-place.

Alternatively, if this takes too much server resources, it would be an improvement to have a link on pending synonyms that leads directly to the info-tab for that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done is:

1. Make the tag directly link to the info page.
2. Provide a pending only sort order

I do not want to make voting super easy, also I want to restrict voting to tag experts.

Comment: This is really confusing. When I click a tag, I expect to see questions (especially the source tag). As I said above, it would be most helpful if just the "pending" text linked to the target tag's info page.

Comment: Okay, much better. I can live with this.

Comment: With two pages of tag synonyms, it's really time intensive to cast votes for tags.  Please add voting to the tags synonyms page.  Also, I think you could have a copy of the tags synonym page on Meta.

Comment: Well, I was going to do some tag synonym voting to help the site, but since you’ve decided to make it deliberately more difficult and annoying than necessary, I guess I won’t.

Comment: "I do not want to make voting super easy". Erm...