# How to upvote and downvote tag synonyms?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

How can I vote for tag synonyms?

For example, I want to downvote the `ecmascript` synonym (I won't discuss the why here). I looked at the `javascript` tag [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=javascript&sort=info&pagesize=30), which told me:

> Users with more than 2000 reputation
>   can **suggest** and **vote** on tag
>   synonyms. Suggestions will be
>   automatically approved when they reach
>   a score of 4, and automatically
>   deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Well, I do have a rep of >2000 and I see a suggestion box, but I can't click on the ‘vote’ text, nor do I see any voting arrows or something like that.

After clicking on [see all tag synonyms »](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms), I get a *way* too cumbersome page to navigate through. I have to browse through all synonyms in the database. Luckily it's right there on the [third page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?page=3&tab=master&filter=active). But I still can't vote those tags up or down; I can merely click on them, in which case I'm redirected to the ‘master’ tag's page.

I know you [don't want the voting to be too easy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58270/add-voting-buttons-to-the-tag-synonym-overview-page/58852#58852), but this is really horrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only vote on a synonym **proposal**. For example, there's currently a proposal to map `[ms-word]` to `[msword]`, so on the [`[msword] info page`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=msword&sort=info&pagesize=30) you can see the `ms-word` proposal, along with upvote/downvote arrows to weigh in:

---

[Screenshot of the [msword] tag synonyms proposal http://mrozekma.com/so-tag-synonyms.png](http://mrozekma.com/so-tag-synonyms.png)

---

Once a synonym has been accepted, it's in the system and there's no way to vote it out; you'd need to post something on the per-site meta requesting that it be removed

Answer (score 1):

Once a synonym proposal reaches 4 upvotes it's accepted by the system and voting is closed.

Conversely, once a synonym proposal reaches -2 votes the proposal is torched by the system.