# Can we know the users that voted on a tag synonym?

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

While supporting a user that was [struggling with a tag synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268990/how-can-i-restrict-my-search-for-a-tag-that-has-been-made-a-synonym) I tried to supply information on who [voted on the tag-synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60410/how-can-i-upvote-and-downvote-tag-synonyms).

Unfortunately nor the [tag synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest)  nor [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/218448/who-synomized-a-tag?tagname=android-manifest) holds the 4 voters:

> Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Only the user proposing the synonym seems to be recorded. I don't see revealing the voters mentioned in the feature request for [Improving tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204244/improving-tag-synonyms).

Is there a functional or technical reason the synonym voters are kept secret?

If there isn't a specific reason can this info be made available, maybe only in SEDE, so it becomes possible to discuss the approved synonym with the voters?