# Allow voting on tag synonyms from list of suggestions

Tags: feature-request, voting, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Add voting buttons to the tag synonym overview page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58270/add-voting-buttons-to-the-tag-synonym-overview-page)

The tag synonyms page has a list of [suggested synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest), so it's easy for users to see which synonyms are available to vote on. However, to actually vote you need to go to each tag info page and vote individually. Is it possible to support voting on synonyms from the list itself? Something like this would be useful:

[image: Mockup of voting from the suggested synonyms list]

Comment: I thought we blacklisted "oops" as a tag for ambiguity...

Comment: I started getting upvotes after Jon found the duplicate. I should post duplicates more often

Comment: lol Maybe that's why there have been so many dupes lately.

Comment: The irony that my script chooses to repair a post with broken images about [tag synonym voting buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329688/295232) is not lost on me ...