# Badge for voting on Tag Synonyms needs a name

Tags: discussion, badges, tag-synonyms

I think its time to bring some of this back to life: [Incentive for proposing and voting on tag Synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58512/incentive-for-proposing-and-voting-on-tag-synonyms)

We are thinking of introducing a couple of new badges for voting on tag synonyms. A bronze for the first vote and a silver for 100 or so. The idea is that it will help us sort through the huge backlog of proposals (300 or so on Stack Overflow)

Any ideas for names for these badges?

Comment: If only the process were [streamlined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74116/allow-voting-on-tag-synonyms-from-list-of-suggestions) :)

Comment: Thanks for working the Tag Synonym issue, streamlining would be great also.

Comment: @Michael I support the streamlining - the multi click stuff is pretty annoying ... also we would need black listing if we made this much easier

Comment: The huge backlog is just caused by bad UI/UX. As a first step, adding vote buttons to the [main tag synonym list](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) would make a **huge** difference. I lost my motivation so many times on this page, no one badge would compensate that. Once the UI is fixed, we can talk about badges.

Answer (score 7):

### Syllogist

Advantages:

- A single word, not a phrase
- A real word, not something totally made up
- Accurately describes what the badge is being awarded for
- Avoids the debate on whether "syllogiser" should be spelled "syllogizer"

Comment: I like this one, nice

Answer (score 0):

equals operator

equivalence expert

affiliator

relational expert

matchmaker

Comment: congruency specialist

Comment: Or perhaps 'syllogist'.

Comment: I quite like "syllogist". One word tag names are nicer than multiple word phrases. And anything that includes the word "operator".

Comment: I agree, one word over a phrase.  If I had to pick only one, I like 'matchmaker'.  But we tend to take a nuanced/unique approach to selecting badge names so perhaps 'syllogist' is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

### Equalizer

### Great Equalizer

### Synonymator

### Simplifier