# Tag synonyms: show suggestions to people who can vote

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

I just found (by surfing other questions) the [dsl](/questions/tagged/dsl) tag (which seems to be used mainly for domain-specific languages, although there is no tag wiki yet), and saw that there also is the [domain-specific-languages](/questions/tagged/domain-specific-languages) tag. The latter should obviously be a tag synonym... I wanted to suggest this, but [it already was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dsl/synonyms) by someone else. I can't vote on it, and looking at the [tag users list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dsl/topusers), there are not many users who can at all.

This suggestion does not show up on the [suggested tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested) page, so I have no idea how long it is already in this suggested state. Why does it not show up there? (Ah, it looks like it shows only the synonyms **I** am allowed vote on. This could be made clear somehow. Also, it could somehow distinguish those I have already voted and those where I don't. )

**Can we do something to ease voting for such synonym proposals**?

- Could we somehow show synonym requests to all users who have the voting rights (particularly, if there are not many such users at all)? Maybe the user page with the tags could have some mark beside the tag when there are such requests, which links to the synonyms page which allows voting? Or even everywhere where this tag is shown (but only for users with the necessary rights)?
- Maybe allow general high-reputation users with a little reputation in this tag to vote, too (maybe only if some proposal is inactive for a long time)?

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58270/add-voting-buttons-to-the-tag-synonym-overview-page/58852#58852) seems to indicate that too much tag synonym voting is not intended - is this right?

On a related topic, reviews for tag wiki (and excerpt) edits could also preferably shown to users who are active in this tag.

---

As there are many upvotes and no answers nor comments: I welcome other ideas on how to do this. (The tag mentioned above is now a synonym.)

Comment: I've posted two solutions + a workaround at [a similar meta-question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128874/169101?does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work).