# Don't let me suggest a tag synonym, if I don't have enough score to do so

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

When I'm on a tag synonyms page, there's a box:

> Suggest a sometag synonym: ________________ [Suggest]

So I type in a new tag and click Suggest.

Often I don't have enough rep in that tag to suggest one, and get an error:

> Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag.

There is a big warning just before the box ("Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms"), but there's no way I can be expected to remember my score in every tag, or go clicking around my profile to check.

It'd be much better to remove the suggestion box entirely if I don't have enough score in that tag, so I don't waste time clicking and typing in a suggestion only for it to be rejected. Maybe replace the box with text saying I don't have enough score.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improving Tag Synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204244/improving-tag-synonyms), specifically *"So our ambitious tag-synonymizers need to click on a link with no knowledge of whether or not a synonym request is actually pending, and then they have to actually have enough score in that tag to actually suggest the synonym. This means that there is a barrier to finding the suggested synonym even before the restriction on voting."*

Comment: I don't think these are duplicates. This is about suggesting. The other appears to mainly be about finding and voting (+1 to that), and doesn't offer a solution to this.

Comment: That is true I s'pose. Related but not identical. Something tells me that the next time they touch the synonym system, it's going to be a big change, but no issue is keeping this here for good measure just in case. It would be a definite improvement at any rate.