# Merge the [touch-events], [touch-event] and [ontouchevent] tags and check other tags by that user

Tags: support, synonym-request

[touch-events](/questions/tagged/touch-events), [touch-event](/questions/tagged/touch-event) and [ontouchevent](/questions/tagged/ontouchevent) are all serving exactly the same purpose (and in fact were created by the same person within half an hour of one another—clearly he misunderstood the idea of tagging). Despite its being the least used of the three, I suggest that [touch-events](/questions/tagged/touch-events) be the canonical form and the others aliases.

This is not an isolated incident; e.g. [keyevent](/questions/tagged/keyevent) and [key-events](/questions/tagged/key-events) immediately stand out as being exact duplicates.

For that reason, [all of WATTO Studios' suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1268895/watto-studios?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) should be checked and duplicates tags removed.

Comment: Such confusion isn't all that surprising, given that [tag synonyms are almost impossible for mere mortals to create](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204244/improving-tag-synonyms).